# Updating DataTable causes crash

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable

When I insert a row into my DataTable with the view selected it seems that my application crashes. Presumably this is related to some cross threading issue, but I'm not entirely sure how to go about working around it. Here's my definition of the DataTable:

```
public class Logging
{
    public DataTable Logs;

    public Logging()
    {
        Logs = new DataTable();
        Logs.Columns.Add("Level", typeof(int));
        Logs.Columns.Add("Message", typeof(string));
    }

    public void LogMessage(int level, string message)
    {
        DataRow row = Logs.NewRow();
        row["Level"] = level;
        row["Message"] = message;
        Logs.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

This generates the DataTable as I expect, and it works fine. I've then bound this to a WPF ListView control, like so:

```
    <ListView x:Name="lvConsole">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Level" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Level}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Message" Width="376" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Message}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Also by adding this into the C#:

```
lvConsole.ItemsSource = Util.Logger.Logs.DefaultView;
```

So, to produce the issue I just open up the form that contains the list view, click on it and scroll around a little, and I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source.
```

Looking at more detail, it appears this is the underlying issue:

```
{"Information for developers (use Text Visualizer to read this):\r\nThis exception was thrown because the generator for control 'System.Windows.Controls.ListView Items.Count:20' with name 'lvConsole' has received sequence of CollectionChanged events that do not agree with the current state of the Items collection.  The following differences were detected:\r\n  Accumulated count 12 is different from actual count 20.  [Accumulated count is (Count at last Reset + #Adds - #Removes since last Reset).]\r\n\r\nOne or more of the following sources may have raised the wrong events:\r\n     System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator\r\n      System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection\r\n       System.Windows.Data.BindingListCollectionView\r\n        System.Data.DataView\r\n(The starred sources are considered more likely to be the cause of the problem.)\r\n\r\nThe most common causes are (a) changing the collection or its Count without raising a corresponding event, and (b) raising an event with an incorrect index or item parameter.\r\n\r\nThe exception's stack trace describes how the inconsistencies were detected, not how they occurred.  To get a more timely exception, set the attached property 'PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel' on the generator to value 'High' and rerun the scenario.  One way to do this is to run a command similar to the following:\n   System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceSources.SetTraceLevel(myItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator, System.Diagnostics.PresentationTraceLevel.High)\r\nfrom the Immediate window.  This causes the detection logic to run after every CollectionChanged event, so it will slow down the application.\r\n"}
```

Does anyone have any idea what I need to do to fix this? I've tried a number of things, one of which is this:

```
private static object _syncLock = new object();

BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(Logs.Rows, _syncLock);
```

This doesn't appear to do anything useful, perhaps it's related to me calling LogMessage from two threads at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I've found a good workaround, but not certain how long it will last. I'll share it regardless in the hope that it is right...

```
    private void logMessage(object parameters)
    {
        object[] Paras = (object[])parameters;
        int level = Convert.ToInt32(Paras[0]);
        string message = (string)(Paras[1]);
        DataRow row = Logs.NewRow();
        row["Level"] = level;
        row["Message"] = message;
        Logs.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    public void LogMessage(int level, string message)
    {
        object lvl = Convert.ToString(level);
        object msg = message;
        object[] ob = { lvl, msg };
        if (Util.client.player.isRunning)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new ParameterizedThreadStart(logMessage), ob);
            ParameterizedThreadStart pts = new ParameterizedThreadStart(logMessage);
        }
    }
```

I've had to create a new method, which uses the applications dispatcher to invoke the method which edits the list, which if I'm correct, will edit the list from the applications main thread (coincidentally, not the one that's writing to the list, but the one that is displaying it constantly).

This is all rather confusing, if anyone else can think of a better way to explain it please go ahead :)